# Roots of log binomial likelihood equation

Tags: roots, approximation, binomial-distribution, log-likelihood

I have been wondering if there is a way to approximate the roots of the log binomial likelihood equation. To be clear the equation is

$$a \cdot \log\left(x\right) + b \cdot \log\left(1 - x\right) = t$$

where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, and $x$ is between 0 and 1. When $t < a \cdot \log\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right) + b \cdot \log\left(\frac{b}{a+b}\right)$, I know there are two real roots between 0 and 1.

I tried a few symbolic solvers such as SymPy, SageMath, Mathematica, Matlab's solver but none of them give me any answers. I can numerically solve it using either Newton's method, secant method or Halley’s method, but there are a few problems. These methods are slow. I need to solve this for many different $a$, $b$, and $t$ values. Another problem is when t is very small, the roots get very closer to the end points 0 and 1, then the algorithms fail to converge.

I believe partly because I am not familiar with the field, and partly because English is not my first language, I couldn't find any literature on this topic. I would appreciate any references to the related literature very much.

Comment: Much improved ! Have a look at the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I prefer to add another answer, since it is based on a totally different approach.*

One of the problem when working with the function
$$f(x)=a \, \log\left(x\right) + b \, \log\left(1 - x\right) - t$$ is that $x$ is a limited and bounded interval.

To unbound the variable, consider the change of variable
$$x=\frac 1{1+e^{-y}}$$ which allows to vary between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

So, replacing and simplifying, now we have to find the zero's of function
$$g(y)=a y-(a+b) \log \left(1+e^y\right)-t$$ Its maximum is at $y_*=\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$ and a series expansion around this point gives
$$g(y)=k-\frac{a b}{2 (a+b)}\left(y-y_*\right)^2-t+O\left(\left(y-y_*\right)^3\right)$$
$$k=\left(a\log(a)+b\log(b)-(a+b) \log(a+b)\right)$$ and then the approximate solutions
$$y_\pm=y_*\pm \sqrt{\frac{2(a+b) (k-t)}{a b}} \implies x_\pm=\frac 1 {1+e^{y_\mp}}$$

Applied to the previous case $(a=1, b=2, t=-5)$, this gives
$$y_-=-\log (2)-\sqrt{15-3 \log \left(\frac{27}{4}\right)}\implies x_-=0.023247$$
$$y_+=-\log (2)+\sqrt{15-3 \log \left(\frac{27}{4}\right)}\implies x_+=0.913073$$

Based on the $y$'s, Newton method converge very fast

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & y_n \\
 0 & -3.738040 \\
 1 & -5.018754 \\
 2 & -4.979452 \\
 3 & -4.979437
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & y_n \\
 0 & 2.351746 \\
 1 & 2.365367 \\
 2 & 2.365354
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

I think that we could combine the two answers to take advantage of the quality of the estimates of $x$ given in the first answer and the nice conditioning of function $g(y)$ defined here.

For each of the root, the path would be
$$x_0 \implies y_0=-\log \left(\frac{1}{x_0}-1\right)\implies y_1=y_0-\frac{g(y_0)}{g'(y_0)}\implies x_1=\frac{1}{1+e^{-y_1}}$$ where
$$g'(y)=\frac{a+b}{1+e^y}-b$$

Applied to the worked example, this would give as solutions
$$9.14146964097\times 10^{-1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad  6.83095206594\times 10^{-3}$$ to be compared to the exact
$$9.14146937658\times 10^{-1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad  6.83095206610\times 10^{-3}$$

Comment: Yes with this update, it is quite fast. There are few problems though. Sometimes a and b get very big and t gets very small, resulting in that the tighter estimations become very close to 0 and 1. So I alternate between the tighter estimations and the estimations given previously in this answer. Now everything works really well. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you look for the zero of function $$f(x)=a \, \log\left(x\right) + b \, \log\left(1 - x\right) - t$$
If $a<b$ there is a small root close to $0$ and a large root. Consider the large one and expand using Taylor
$$f(x)=b\,\log(1-x)-a(1-x)+O\left((1-x)^2\right)-t$$ and then an *approximate* solution for the large root
$$\color{red}{x_2 \sim 1+\frac b a W\left(-\frac{a }{b}e^{\frac{t}{b}}\right)}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

For the small root
$$f(x)=a \log (x)-b x+O\left(x^2\right)-t$$
$$\color{red}{x_1 \sim -\frac a b W\left(-\frac{b }{a}e^{\frac{t}{a}}\right)}$$

Let us try with $a=1$, $b=2$ and $t=-5$. This gives $x_2=0.914322$ and $x_1=0.00683063$ while the exact solutions are $x_2=0.914147$ and $x_1=0.00683095$.

With these estimates, Newton method should work like a charm. For the worked example, Newton iterates are.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.9143221615 \\
 1 & 0.9141471262 \\
 2 & 0.9141469377
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.006830627434 \\
 1 & 0.006830952058 \\
 2 & 0.006830952066
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I learned a lot from both of your answers. Thank you! One question, does this also work when $a>b$? I can't see why it wouldn't work. It seems to give very close approximations also when $a>b$. I understand that when $b>a$, the distance between the small root and 0 is smaller than the distance between the large root and 1. But, I don't understand how this is being used in the derivation. And when $a = b$, I can solve it with quadratic formula, that case is straight-forward.

Comment: @atb. In the case where $a<b$, let $x=1-y$ and it is the same problem.

Comment: @atb. I meant : if $a>b$ let $x=1-y$ and compute the largest root for $y$ and then $x=1-y$